# SharePoint Search: Default Content Access Account Access Denied

Tags: search, sharepoint

My SharePoint Farm has three web applications;

Intranet

MySites

Extranet

All these web applications are hosted on port 443 and are viewable over HTTPS.

Alternative Access Mapping are configured in the same way for each web application.

Each web application uses NTLM authentication.

The problem

The Intranet web application is the only web application that search indexes. All other web applications return nothing. Even though all the start addresses are correctly inserted into the content source. (There is only one content source for all web applications).

The crawl log includes top-level errors for the two web applications that are not indexed detailing the following information;

```
Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled. ( SearchID = 81287A7C-FFA5-4D5E-AA92-C2E2DAB81B50 )
```

The Default Content Access Account has “Full Read” permissions to all three web applications and I’m not sure why I need to create a crawl rule to crawl the “MySite” and “Extranet” repository when there isn’t one required for the “Intranet” web application and so I can’t see this being the problem.

I can successful view both web applications when I’m logged in with the Default Content Access account too.

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by updating the host entry file in the crawl servers. Basically the crawl servers had an entry for the web application that was getting indexed, but didn't have an entry for the two web applications that were not getting indexed.

I found these URLs helpful;

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25863.access-is-denied-verify-that-either-the-default-content-access-account-has-access-to-this-repository-or-add-a-crawl-rule-to-crawl-this-repository.aspx

http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/access-is-denied-verify-that-either.html